# 90s (or earlier) short story: girls kidnapped and married to aliens, cry upon visiting Earth again because they miss the perfect aliens' kingdom

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story I read in high school (1995-1999). I don't remember the title or the author. It was in a book of science fiction short stories. I have tried to find it online, and spoke to others in the class but no one could remember anything about it.

The story was about a race of aliens who take girls from Earth, they would be given a rose. After being taken and married off, the girls would be permitted to return to Earth. During their visit to Earth, the girls would spend the entire visit crying. This made the other humans think that the girls were miserable with the aliens in space, but it turned out that the aliens and their kingdom were considered so beautiful and pure that the girls would cry at being away from it.